# The application of recursive SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, intuition, numerical-linear-algebra

Given an n*m matrix A, the SVD decomposition of A is  ${\rm SVD}(A)$= $USV^t$.
The application of SVD to the product of U and S gives as a result the same matrices multiplied by the identity matrix, i.e, $${\rm SVD}(US)=U*S*Id$$

Can anyone explain me the intuition or the proof behind SVD yielding the same result matrices as the input matrix!

Thanks.

Comment: Don't you think $Id^t=Id$?